# Javascript - How to record the selection value as an array from multi selection dropdown list (including add and delete)

Tags: javascript

As we know, the select2 widget can be used to build a multi selection dropdown list for adding items and deleting items. How can we use a list to record the option value for adding and deleting? 
for example

```js
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month'
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
</html>
```

For instance, if I select January and February, the array result[] should append 1 and 2 to the list. If remove January, the result list should remove value 1 as well and remind result[2].

Comment: But you can't select two at once, or remove an option. There's literally no option to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the `select`'s `change` event, and retrieve an array of the selected values with `$("#example").val()`

```js
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month'
});

$("#example").on("change", function() {
    var result = $(this).val().map(i => parseInt(i));
    console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
</html>
```

Or, if you wanted them as text, you could `.map` the selected elements:

```js
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month'
});

$("#example").on("change", function() {
    var result = $(this).find("option:selected").map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get();
    console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for your solution. Just wonder how to append the number to be int rather than string. I used "var result = parseInt($(this).val())", but it does not work. How do I parse it to be INT?

Comment: @user3651247 I've edited my first snippet to parse integers. You can't parse an entire array (like `parseInt( $(this).val() )`), but rather by mapping each value: `myArray.map((item) => parseInt( item ))`